# Mysql query vs php query give me wrong results

Tags: php, mysql

I have an access log database with more than 110,000 records.

I run the next query on my console:

```
SELECT COUNT(`remote_host`), `remote_host` FROM `access_log`
GROUP BY `remote_host` HAVING COUNT(`remote_host`) > 99
ORDER BY COUNT(`remote_host`) DESC
```

I have that result.
[Mysql query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0FSf.jpg)

With 143 records.

But when I execute a PHP code with the same query, the result is some diferent with 174 records (??).
[Query with PHP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qg0Q.jpg)

And the first record have the next values : 89.248.174.171, 14160

2365 vs 14160 !!??

The second result it's OK.
But... the all next results are diferent too !!

The PHP code it's simple:

```
$q_1 = "SELECT COUNT(`remote_host`), `remote_host` FROM `access_log` GROUP BY `remote_host` HAVING COUNT(`remote_host`) > 99 ORDER BY COUNT(`remote_host`) DESC ;";

$aItems = doQuery($con, $q_1);
echo count($aItems)."<br/>";
var_dump($aItems);
```

Function doQuery:

```
function doQuery($con, $query) {
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

    $arr = array();
    if ($result) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
            $arr[] = $row;
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just define a COUNT by using AS in PHP

```
SELECT COUNT(`remote_host`) AS RHOST, `remote_host` FROM `access_log`
GROUP BY `remote_host` HAVING COUNT(`remote_host`) > 99
ORDER BY COUNT(`remote_host`) DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've the same result. 174 records.   0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'RHOST' => string '14513' (length=5)
      'remote_host' => string '89.248.174.171' (length=14)...